# How to set environment variables in ECMA 6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mean-stack, pm2

I am trying to set up environment variable of my project locally like below in my main.js file

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'localdev';
```

but the localdev environment is not configured.

I have localdev.json file in config folder.

NOTE: node version 6.3.1 , pm2 version 2.0.18 ,ECMA6

Comment: Can you provide an example demostrating that it doesn't work?

What are you trying to do? Something like `node main.js; echo $NODE_ENV;`?

Comment: Sounds like there's much more you need to tell us. e.g. _but the localdev environment is not configured._ what do you mean?